# Download PDF from soap web service

Tags: asp.net, soap

I am using following code to download PDF from a SOAP service. It works fine but instead of content in the PDF file, all pages are blank.

```
string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "request.txt";
string response = HttpSOAPRequest(GetRequestXML(path), null, "https://soap.service", "http://tempuri.org/retrieveContract");

string[] seperator = new string[] {"--MIME_Boundary"};
string[] splitRes = response.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string xx = splitRes[1];

byte[] final  = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xx.Trim());
```

PDF with same number of page as retruned by the soap service gets created - but all pages are blank.

Please suggest, what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for us, replace the last line by

```
byte[] final = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(xx.Trim())));
```

Comment: It did not work. Instead gave following error: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. Exception Details: System.FormatException: